# Key storagein a CMOS RAM?

Tags: c, encryption-symmetric, encryption, key-storage

IS it possible to store the KEY (secret KEY for encryption and decryption) in a CMOS RAM for making a key secure from tampering? (I know contents of RAM are lost when our computer is turned off)

Comment: tampering by a hacher who can access to the device. (a hacher who wants to access the key)

Answer (score 1):

If you can store key in CMOS RAM, why hacker can not read from it? Reading from CMOS is much more simple than writing to it.

It is theoretically possible to store your data into CMOS, but it will be vendor (or even model) dependent. Different BIOSes uses CMOS RAM differently and you can't know what part of RAM is free for usage.

Much better will be use SMART card. They can guarantee that key saved into it *never* will left card (all cryptography is done inside SMART card). So you once save key into card and then only say 'decrypt (or encrypt) this buffer for me'.

**UPD:**

There was a long discussion in comments. Summarizing, there are next ways to protect keys:

1. Use external secured cryptography module. For example: smart card, HSM.
2. Prevent physical access for unauthorized personnel. For example: safe, locking case, alarm on opening case, etc.
3. Demand (administratively or programmatically) that access to a device is only can be done by group of personnel, not individuals. For example: two security officers know only his own part of password to access a device.
4. Built system based on a [Chain of Trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_trust).
5. Use [TPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) (Trusted platform module).

Comment: Note that sometimes motherboards do have a TPM (trusted platform module) chip on it, which you can use for secure key storage, given that it is present, enabled and that you have access to it. Basically the TPM module is a smart card chip on a motherboard, but it can store encrypted keys outside of the chip, and reload them later.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. What do you mean by outside of the chip? if a hacker can access the motherboard and smart card chip, can he read the key from that?

Comment: @Saghar, no, properly programmed smart card chip does not allow to read key for anyone. You can write ( or command chip to generate) new key, but anyone can read key that stored there. More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card#Cryptographic_smart_cards

Comment: Thank you for your information. Unfortunatelly it is not possible to add the smart cards in our devices. Hardware solution is not possible at the moment, do you have any software solution for storing a key in a disk or some where else.  (storing tamper free a key on disk (or anywhere else) is a question?)

Comment: @saghar you can store key on disk as ordinary file, just encrypt it on user's password. So every time, user want to use key, he must enter password to decrypt the keyfile. This is common method in cryptography: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passphrase

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is a good solution but this solution just works for maned-devices but in this case devices are unmaned and there is no user to enter the password. So for using a password we need also to store a password which is exactly the same problem with the key! where we can store the password?

Comment: @saghar, I see the point. If your device is unmanned and you can't use external security devices - only solution is to prevent unauthorized access by physical means: safe, locks, guards, alarm on opening case, etc. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140-2 for more information.

Comment: Well, this is an option but for this case there is already a fence around devices to not let hackers to enter the protected area but the problem is with dissatisfied employee who have access to the device. The whole point is storing a key in a way that a dissatissfied employee who have complete access to the device can not read the key or access the key. This is a problem which is a puzzel for me and I haven't find a solution yet for that. (unmaned- device , no hardware solution, protect against dissatisfied authorized employee!)

Comment: @saghar, Security protocols for many cryptographic systems demands, that access to a device can only has group of people (not one). E.g., to change keys in ATM you need at least two security officers, every of them holds only part of the secret (it can be password for device console for example). This guarantees that no one individually can tamper device.

Comment: Thank you for your solution but just imagin in this case there are different employeess who have access to the devices for different reasons such as construction or protection or whatever.... if we set such a rule for them (or as you said set a password for device console for example) we need at least two person at the same time to do the same resposibility (or enter the device) which means that at least two employees are needed to be payed for one job. I think it is not pleasent for the owner of the company who pays two times for one job!

Comment: @saghar. There is a simple rule: The more system is secure, the less it is easy to use. And vice versa. I proposed number of solutions, you should select 'golden mean' between usability and security.

Comment: Thank you so much for your information and solution. I will think about them.

Comment: Do you have any solution for the problem in whitch the hacker can access the device completely and you want to design a security for storing a key on unmanned device? (Software solution)for example try to designe in a way that the security of the system not exaclty depend on the key I mean remove the dependancy, and separate the security to key and something else for communication? If you have any software solution like this I will be grateful to let me know.

Comment: @saghar. The only solutions is a chain of trust ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_trust ): CPU loads only signed BIOS, BIOS starts only signed bootloader, bootloader starts only signed kernel, kernel itself allows execute only signed binaries and these binaries has no function to show the key to a user. But this is almost impossible on general systems (like Windows or even Linux on x86). You well need special hardware. Also, you may try to use TPM (as mentioned on first comment), but there can be another problems.

Comment: chain of trust is for computer security not network security, if I choose this as an option how it is possible to enter a same key in all devices, beacuse all devices should have a same key and it is needed to load the key manualy on devices... how we can use a chain of trust here!

Comment: @saghar, your program can implement function "Store key", but not function "show key". If any other program on your system will not allow to show key, then no one will have ability to get installed key from the system. *But* your system must allow to execute only *your* *signed* programs.

Comment: would you please explain a little bit more how we can load or enter the key into our devices and where the signed program store the key? in disk? if the key stores in a disk does it need any program to show the key? or the hacker as soon as access the place of the key which has been stored can read it?